# Determine if a coordinate is inside a vector shape

Tags: shapes, bezier

I have a shape defined by a set of quadratic bezier curves (point0 (x,y),controlPoint(x,y),point1(x,y)). This shape is always closed but can be composed of concave and convex areas (ex: shape can be a oval or it can be a winding snake . Is there an algorithm that can determine if a coordinate (x,y) is inside the closed shape formed by the given set of quadratic bezier curves?

Thanks for your time

Comment: If you can convert the curves to an approximation with line segments, it will be easy. Working with the Bezier math is going to be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach is a simple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon test. Flatten the curves, and treat it as a (finite) series of lines, then test. To improve performance, you can also treat your shape as a number of distinct regions, each bounded by a bezier curve, with (possibly overlapping) hulls. If the point is inside the hull, only flatten that curve and then do the real test.

Variations on the scheme are varied.

Comment: Your demo in Figure 23.1 http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#shapes would probably be of interest to the op.

Comment: I considered adding that, but the code that uses actually takes a few shortcuts that makes it report the wrong thing under certain conditions, so I didn't want to link to technically incorrect (but for demonstration purposes good enough) code.